# cannot convert NSURLSession in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

This code works great on swift 2, but i do not managed to convert it to swift 3....

```
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Swift 3 version of your code:

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue:OperationQueue.mainQueue())
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue:OperationQueue.main)
```

Swift 3 contains [the great rename](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0005-objective-c-name-translation.md) proposal, so you'll have to remove the `NS` prefix from foundation classes.

Also in your snippet, some getters have become variables, to know how they changed check out the class definition from XCode, the documentation or the proposal linked above.